# YA sci fi novel a group of kids find out they're alien royalty. One of the girls has blue skin and can read minds

Tags: story-identification, novel

I've been looking for this book for years! It's about a group of kids, and someone gathers them all up. They find out they have powers, and are alien princes and princesses.  They each have a different power.  One of them is a girl with blue skin, and she can read minds and she thinks she's ugly.  At one point in time, they have to all go inside one of the girls' mind and find her because something traumatic happened so she was hiding in her own mind. And I think she tries to drown them maybe? I just remember it being really dark and dangerous inside. I don't remember any physical characteristics of the book. I read it probably in the early to mid 2000's. I think it was just in the YA section at my local library.
I've googled for hours trying to find it, I'm hoping a human can maybe help now!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Approximately when did you read it?  Do you remember what the cover looked like?  Please check out the [suggestions for story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.